# How to get just "ids" which are not in the table "service_gos" (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I want to return only those "gos" that are not registered in the "service_gos" table by comparing "gos.id" with "service_gos.gos_id"

[image]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `$results = Gos::whereDoesntHave("service_gos")->get();`